# Make number a given number of digits using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to convert 1, 11, 111, and 1111 to 0001, 0011, 0111, and 1111, and then append some text to the resultant.  I know how to format the cells as custom 4 digits, but this does not allow me to use them in a formula and append text.

Comment: Do you need to always append the same text or will it vary?

Comment: @ChristopheC  Text is appended from a different column.  LDC3's solution works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add leading zeros, use the TEXT function:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000")
```

[image]

To append text, use *&*

```
= C1&B1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using LibreOffice, but you should have these functions in Excel:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"0000")," ",A2)
```